# Why am I unable to transfer Resident Evil 2 from my PS3 to my Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, resident-evil-2-1998

I recently purchased FFVIII, Alundra and Resident Evil 2 from PSN and downloaded them on my PS3 with the intention of transferring them to my Vita to play on the move.

When I enter the content manager screen with the vita connected to the PS3 I can see FFVIII and Alundra, and have successfully transferred them, but for some reason Resident Evil 2 doesn't show up.

The description on the PlayStation store states that the game is compatible with the Vita so why is it not showing up?

I have tried repeatedly connecting/disconnecting content manager as this was suggested on some forms but with no success.

edit: Both the Vita and the PS3 are the latest firmware at time of writing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but did you update the firmware to 1.8?

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference for Ps3 -> Vita games, but when I used to keep a PSN membership, some of the games would expire if I bought/got them with my PSN membership(usually the ones that were free). You might want to check if it is expired if you got RE2 for free.

Comment: @leety I purchased RE2 and did not get it for free via Playstation Plus.

Comment: I don't see RE2 in the download store for the Vita so it's probably not copyable yet. I'll download it and give it a try tonight though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the install to Vita/PSP from PS3 action fails. Typically the optimal solutions is to setup your handheld so it is activated with the same PSN profile as you use on your PS3. Then, once you log into the PSN store from your handheld you can go to your account transaction history and download directly to the system from there over WiFi.

edit: After some additional research on this I found no news about it being pulled, but I did find lot's of people asking why it's gone now. While I know it bypasses Sony's Q&A process, there does appear to be a method for installing it to the Vita anyways that you can read about here: [joystiq.com/2012/08/28/](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/08/28/report-vita-workaround-lets-you-transfer-more-psone-games-from/)... **NOTE! YMMV and since this does bypass quality controls, installing software this way could risk issues on your Vita, so please be aware of this risk before attempting**

Comment: I have gone to my downloads list using the vita and next to RE2 it says this is not compatible with the PS vita system, (or words to that effect) even though when I purchased the game on PS3 the description said it was compatible with vita. Good suggestion but has not solved the problem.

Comment: Ok, then that answers your question. For whatever reason they have flagged it as not supported at this time. Beyond this all you could do is write into Sony's support for assistance and see what they tell you. For all we know, maybe it's an error in the shop? Hopefully they will give you the full scoop.

Comment: I've been trying to research this more and have found no news about it being pulled, but lot's of people asking why it's gone now. While I know it bypasses Sony's Q&A process, there does appear to be a method for installing it to the Vita anyways that you can read about here: http://www.joystiq.com/2012/08/28/report-vita-workaround-lets-you-transfer-more-psone-games-from/  **NOTE! YMMV and since this does bypass quality controls, installing software this way could risk issues on your Vita, so please be aware of this risk before attempting.**

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Just bought it for my Vita now - the product text says PSP and Playstation 3 only, but it definitely does work. Runs very smooth on the Vita - impressed!

Answer (score 0):

There is a glitch with the game and the ability to transfer it to vita has apparently been disabled.

Comment: Do you have any source for this? Or is this an assumption?